# Differs type parameters in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

TypeScript allows to pass differs type parameters like:

```
public getClassesNumbers(classes: ClassesAndSubjects[] | SchoolClass[]) {}
```

But what I function inside expects only `SchoolClass[]` parameter type for `classes`?

```
this.functionInside(classes: SchoolClass[], true)
```

Is it obligatorily to specify `ClassesAndSubjects[] | SchoolClass[]` type also fo function inside?

It forces to make duplicates of code.

Comment: if `this.functionInside` accepts only  `SchoolClass[]` type then why are you using a union type as `classes: ClassesAndSubjects[] | SchoolClass[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a function that accepts a union type and call a function inside that only accepts one of them, you only have to use a **type guard**, so that function is only called when the true type of the argument is what that function expects:

```
public getClassesNumbers(classes: ClassesAndSubjects[] | SchoolClass[]) {
    if (classes && (classes[0] instanceof SchoolClass)) {
       // we can safely call functionInside:
       functionInside(classes as SchoolClass[]);
    } else { 
       // ... something ...
    }
}
```

This works if `ClassesAndSubjects` and `SchoolClass` are classes. If they were interfaces, you won't be able to use `instanceof`, so you should have to use a different type guard. For example, if `SchoolClass` has a property `someProp` that `ClassesAndSubjects` does not:

```
public getClassesNumbers(classes: ClassesAndSubjects[] | SchoolClass[]) {
    if (classes && classes[0] && ('someProp' in classes[0])) {
       // we can safely call functionInside:
       functionInside(classes as SchoolClass[]);
    } else { 
       // ... something ...
    }
}
```

The third option is defining a true **type guard**:

```
function isSchoolClassArray(x: any[]): x is SchoolClass[] {
    return (x !== null && x.length > 0) ? ('someProp' in x[0]): false;
}

public getClassesNumbers(classes: ClassesAndSubjects[] | SchoolClass[]) {
    if (isSchoolClassArray(classes)) {
       // we can safely call functionInside:
       functionInside(classes);
    } else { 
       // ... something ...
    }
}
```

The advantage of the last option is that TypeScript will know what type `classes` is inside the `if` and `else`, so no need for type assertions.

Of course, in both these cases, if the array is empty the type guards will fail, but in that case it won't matter because `functionInside` will also receive an empty array